# Spring boot application with JPA, many to many relation with additional attributes returning infinite recursion error

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jackson-databind

I tried to return the entity directly as response resulted in error as "Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)", I would like to get the response in both forms with out transforming the data. Can some one suggest work around. Adding the Entity structure for your reference.

Employee Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<EmployeeStream> streams = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Stream Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Stream {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long streamId;
    private String streamName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stream")
    private Set<EmployeeStream> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

EmployeeStream Entity with additional Attribute experience

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeStream {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLPOYEE_ID")
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STREAM_ID")
    private Stream stream;

    private double experience;
}
```

I would like to retrieve data in both forms

```
{
  "employeeId": 1,
  "firstName": "George",
  "lastName": "Stephen",
  "role": "developer",
  "streams": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "stream": {
        "streamId": 1,
        "streamName": "Java"
      },
      "experience": 1.2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "stream": {
        "streamId": 2,
        "streamName": "Node JS"
      },
      "experience": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "stream": {
    "streamId": 1,
    "streamName": "Java",
    "employees": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "employee": {
          "employeeId": 1,
          "firstName": "George",
          "lastName": "Stephen",
          "role": "developer"
        },
        "experience": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "employee": {
          "employeeId": 1,
          "firstName": "Davis",
          "lastName": "Tom",
          "role": "developer"
        },
        "experience": 0.5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` as used in the below in below code.

**Employee entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<EmployeeStream> streams = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Stream entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Stream {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long streamId;
    private String streamName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stream")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<EmployeeStream> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**EmployeeStream entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeStream {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLPOYEE_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STREAM_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Stream stream;

    private double experience;
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) and [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-managed-reference.html)

**Update**: Previously `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` was misplaced, corrected the same.

**Note**: If still faced any problem then try removing `@JsonManagedReference` from `Stream` and `Employee` entities.

Comment: it doesn't worked out, got error like: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'streams': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type

Comment: @Basil Daniel, I have updated the answer you can try the same. if that does not work then try removing `@JsonManagedReference` from `Stream` and `Employee` entities as mentioned in note